# Switch case doesn't work and give 0 values

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I tried this switch and loop, but it only gives me 0 values when I expected it should be incrementing for all display "yes". May I know where goes wrong?
I am new to this javascript.

```
for (var i=3; i<=62; i++){
  var quesNum = i - 2;
  if (activeSheet.getRange(row, i).getDisplayValue() == "yes") {
    switch (quesNum) {
    case 1: case 3: case 5: case 12:
      ++realistic;
      break;
    case 2: case 6: case 9: case 14:
      ++investigative;
      break;
    case 4: case 8: case 11: case 15:
      ++artistic; 
    case 7: case 10: case 13: case 16:
      ++conventional;
      break;
      default:
```

Comment: What are the values for `activeSheet.getRange(row, i).getDisplayValue()`? Tried logging this?

Comment: it is a data for either yes or no, as respondents will answer yes or no. and I need to count how many yes for each row and total up.

Comment: Your code seems to be returning correct values for the variables, Considering `activeSheet.getRange(row, i).getDisplayValue()` is giving values "yes". Print the values before if condition and see if it is as expected.

Comment: You must give the code as complete as possible in order to reproduce the result.
However, taking a quick look, you are missing three closing brackets (switch, if, for). And after ++artistic should go a break, right? Also, why put "default:" if you don't do anything in that case?

Comment: it doesn't give value "yes" after log.....uhm, so I need to change the getRange part?

Comment: Now, you've found the root cause, fix it and this code should work.

Comment: I do put closing brackets in my own codes, but not here, sorry for the missing information here. but you get the point of not putting the default. 

my previous code of getRange part showed error but all the while it is working in other template.  so I wonder why this time not work only.